# how to update only a few keys in a map in clojure?

Tags: string, dictionary, clojure

I have a map in which i want to update the values(which are strings) 
but i want to update only a few keys not all the keys.

I am new and have no idea how to do it.

Is it possible to update only a few keys in a Clojure map keeping the rest same?

Comment: How do you want to update the keys? Apply a function to them or replace them with new values?

Comment: replace them with new value

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`update` is a valid way to do it if you want to apply a function to your values. otherwise, you could just assoc new values to the map

```
(def example {:a "a" :b "b" :c "c"})
(assoc example
       :a "foo"
       :c "bar")
#=> {:a "foo" :b "b" :c "bar")
```

or `update-in` for nested data

```
(def example {:data {:a "a" :b "b" :c "c"}})
(update-in example [:data] assoc 
           :a "foo" 
           :c "bar")
#=> {:data {:a "foo" :b "b" :c "bar"}}
```

Comment: These two plus `merge` and `into`.

Comment: @StefanKamphausen true

Answer (score 2):

The following will update only keys `:a` and `:b`:

```
(def example {:a 1 :b 2 :c 3})
(-> example
    (update :a inc)
    (update :b inc))
;; {:a 2, :b 3, :c 3}
```

Answer (score 1):

Trying to summarize comments and answers so far...

There are several ways to update only some of the keys in your map. Which one is the best depends on

- Is your data structure nested?

  - If nested, use `assoc-in` instead of `assoc` or `update-in` instead of `update`.
- Do you compute the new values based on the old one?

  - If you need the old values use `update` and `update-in` over `assoc` and `assoc-in`.
- How many keys do you have and how do you have them?

  - The functions `assoc`, `assoc-in`, `update`, and `update-in` all use recursion under the hood for more than one key. With many keys you may run into stack overflow exceptions. The same is true for the notation using `->` which rewrites your code into nested calls.
  - In such cases, use `into` or `merge` if you'd use `assoc` otherwise.
  - Using `into` or `merge` would also be easier if you don't have a fixed set of keys to update but something which is computed at run-time.
  - Note that `into` may be faster than `merge` as it uses a polymorphic `reduce` under the hood.
  - If you're computing new values based on the old ones, i.e. would use `update` otherwise, consider iterating over your map using `reduce` once and collect the new values. This is more low-level but may avoid iterating twice depending on your scenario.

Examples

Please see (and upvote :-) other responses for examples with `assoc`, `assoc-in`, `update`, and `update-in`.

```
(def sample-map {:a 1 :b 2 :c 3})
(def new-values {:b 22 :c 33})
(into sample-map new-values)
(merge sample-map new-values)
```